# Hybris : Is it possible to ignore impex line if code is null?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I want to import media in such a way that if code is null, then hybris should ignore it otherwise it will pass it. Here is my Impex

```
INSERT_UPDATE Media;mediaFormat(qualifier);code[unique=true][allownull=true];youtubeURL;mime[default='video/mp4'];$catalogVersion;folder(qualifier)[default=images]
```

I have one CSV file which having multiple set of data for products. Some products having media, some are not. So I am trying to allowing null in code attribute but its not working.

I checked with `impex.legacy.mode=true` also but no luck. Its still throwing error. May be it can be possible through beanshell but not sure how to do. I dont want to write custom translator for that. Please give me some possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of thinking, i could not find any proper solution except to create my own processor. Here is the Solution

```
public class MediaProcessor extends DefaultImportProcessor
{

@Override
public void init(final ImpExImportReader reader)
{
    super.init(reader);
}

@Override
public Item processItemData(final ValueLine valueLine) throws ImpExException
{
    Item item = null;
    final ValueEntry codeEntry = valueLine.getValueEntry(2);
    final String mediaCode = codeEntry.getCellValue();
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(mediaCode))
    {
        item = super.processItemData(valueLine);
    }
    return item;
}
}
```

Impex should be like this ..

```
 INSERT_UPDATE Media[processor=com.hybris.core.impex.processor.MediaProcessor];mediaFormat(qualifier);code[unique=true];youtubeURL;mime[default='video/mp4'];$catalogVersion;folder(qualifier)[default=images]
```

This won't rescue error. But it will not throw Null Pointer Exception as i was getting in my console (A big one really hate this). So if `code = null` System will dump that line and proceed to next.

## UPDATE :

A quick hack solved my problem. Here is a proper solution to dump a complete line if code = null (as per my requirement)

One line made everything working like a charm!!!

`valueLine.resolve(item, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);`

## Full Code

```
public class MediaProcessor extends DefaultImportProcessor
{

    @Override
    public void init(final ImpExImportReader reader)
    {
       super.init(reader);
    }

    @Override
    public Item processItemData(final ValueLine valueLine) throws ImpExException
    {
        Item item = null;
        final ValueEntry codeEntry = valueLine.getValueEntry(2);
        final String mediaCode = codeEntry.getCellValue();
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(mediaCode))
        {
           item = super.processItemData(valueLine);
        }
        else
        {
           valueLine.resolve(item, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Randomly trying legacy mode will not help.

You need to rethink your conversion from CSV files to Impex.

Comment: Can we not able to do something usign Beanshell ?